# Refresh React google maps Marker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const MyMapComponent = compose(
  withProps({
    googleMapURL:
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={myKey}&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places",
    loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    containerElement: <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />,
    mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  }),
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)((props) => {
  return (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={5}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629 }}
      defaultOptions={defaultMapOptions}
    >
      {props.isMarkerShown && (
        <>
          {props.results?.map((latLng, index) => (
            <Marker
              key={index}
              position={{
                lat: latLng.geometry.location.lat,
                lng: latLng.geometry.location.lng,
              }}
            />
          ))}
        </>
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  );
});

const MapComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.citiesLoaded === true) props.fetchLocations();
  }, [props.citiesLoaded, props.jobAlertCities]);

  return <MyMapComponent isMarkerShown={true} results={props.latLng} />;
};
```

Above is the code, what happens is when the props.results change with different array elements the previous Marker stays in the same place along with the new markers and the map doesn't refresh.
Is there any way to remove the previous markers or refresh the GoogleMap component.